# Iterating over an associative array in bash with keys as boolean true false

Tags: bash, loops, key, associative-array

```
 #!/bin/bash
 key1=true
 key2=true
 filter_param1=filter1
 filter_param2=filter2
 declare -A arr=( [$key1]=$filter_param1 [$key2]=$filter_param2 ) 
 for key in ${!arr[@]}; do
 echo "key value is " $key
 if [ "$key" == "true" ] ; then
 echo $key ${arr[${key}]}
 fi
 done
```

The above code iterates only once and if filter_param1 and filter_param2 are both false or both true. For all other cases it iterates twice. Can i know the reason why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because if `$key1` and `$key2` are the same string, then the latest assignment to that key sets its value.

if you print out the array after the declaration, you'll see it only has one item in it if the keys are the same.